# Are there any open source print management programs?

Tags: untagged

Green initiatives are being pushed onto public organizations, but the price of print chargeback software I've found exceeds the annual expense of actually printing. Is there an open source tool to track and charge library patrons for printouts without breaking the bank?

Comment: Educational environments need this stuff like whoa, and it needs to be bulletproof. I haven't run into any, but would like to know if any exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PyKota** together with **Bifrost** is really a nice setup:

PyKota: http://www.pykota.com/
Bifrost: http://bifrost.projects.linpro.no/

Comment: Interesting. I really like the SheevaPlug approach.

Answer (score 1):

Currently looking at [Pykota](http://www.pykota.com/), it did had commercial support, until the main developer moved to an Island in the South Pacific - who says Open Source doesn't pay?

It works by slipping in behind your existing CUPS server and manges users, queues, quotas, costs etc.  Will advise if it works out for us.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's not enough, but [papercut](http://www.papercut.com/products/free_software/) is free for a maximum of 5 users.

Papercut also have a free tool called [print logger](http://www.papercut.com/products/free_software/print_logger/). I never used it, but, seems that it could help.